# How to create checkbox filter for ng-repeat list using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create checkbox for ng-repeat list. I'm facing some issues.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="findname" placeholder="Search Name"  />
<ul>
    <li class="no-decoration" ng-repeat="tech in technologyArray">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tech.on" />{{tech.u_proffession}}
    </label>
    {{tech.on}}
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li  ng-repeat="stu in students  | filter:findname | filter:myFunc ">                
        <strong>Name :{{stu.u_name}}</strong><br />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var ngApp = angular.module('angapp',[]);
ngApp.controller('angCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.myFunc = function(a) {
    for(tech in $scope.technologyArray){
            var t = $scope.technologyArray[tech];
            if(t.on && a.technology.indexOf(t.u_proffession) > -1){
                return true;   
            }               
        }
    };
    $scope.technologyArray = [{ u_proffession: "developer", on: false}, {u_proffession:"driver", on:false}];
    $http.get("data.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.students= response.data.records
    });
});
```

**JSON ARRAY**

```
{"records":[{"u_name":"adrian","u_mail":"abc@gmail.net","u_proffession":"developer"},{...}]}
```

`1000 Rows`

The simple search `ng-model="findname"` is working fine when i remove the checkbox filter inside the ng-list `| filter:myFunc`. But when i add both of them in `ng-list` then no data showing in `student` list and also text search does not working. I wanted to use both of them.

Can anyone guide me where i'm wrong that i can fix my issue. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You.

Comment: filter:myFunc is a function shouldn't it be like this way filter:myFunc() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am definitely not a fan of putting filter functions in controllers. In that vein, I would recommend writing an actual filter.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.technologyArray = [{
      u_proffession: "developer",
      on: false
    }, {
      u_proffession: "driver",
      on: false
    }];
    $scope.students = [{
      "u_name": "adrian",
      "u_mail": "abc@gmail.net",
      "u_proffession": "developer"
    }, {
      "u_name": "adam",
      "u_mail": "def@gmail.net",
      "u_proffession": "driver"
    }, {
      "u_name": "alex",
      "u_mail": "ghi@gmail.net",
      "u_proffession": "developer"
    }, {
      "u_name": "allen",
      "u_mail": "jkl@gmail.net",
      "u_proffession": "driver"
    }];
  })
  .filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input, techs) {
      if(!techs || techs.length === 0) return input;
      var out = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
        angular.forEach(techs, function(tech) {
          if (item.u_proffession === tech.u_proffession) {
            out.push(item);
          }
        });
      });
      return out;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="findname" placeholder="Search Name">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tech in technologyArray">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tech.on">{{tech.u_proffession}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="stu in students | filter:{u_name: findname} | customFilter:(technologyArray|filter:{on:true})">
      <strong>Name :{{stu.u_name}}</strong> ({{stu.u_proffession}})
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine as i wanted only one thing wanted to ask that currently data is showing only when i filter by checkbox otherwise nothing to show. So is that possible to show all data on page load.

Comment: I updated the snippet. To show all items on page load just make the check boxes checked by default.

Comment: Now its showing only filtered record, i'm asking about all records, Also search filter does not working.

Comment: I wanted to show all the records on page load that i can filter the data from the records other wise page will be blank.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding, but I've modified the way the filter works. Only those check boxes that are checked will be passed to the custom filter. If no check boxes are passed then nothing is filtered by the custom filter. The search filter is working fine when I run the code snippet so I'm not sure why it's not working when you do.

Comment: I'm sorry, your code is absolutely working fine. But it does not working on my side because i'm getting array through `data.php`  i mentioned in the question, i think some code `$http.get("data.php").then(...)` is different  that's why something issue is reamaining. Your answer is correct thank you so much